# How can I set Diablo 3 to work across 3 monitors? (in Eyefinity: 6016 x 1080 resolution)

Tags: diablo-iii

I created my eyefinity group on my desktop to span **6016 x 1080** resolution, but I can only see 1920 x 1080 (as max resolution) in the video settings in Diablo 3.  Is it possible to play D3 while in Eyefinity?  If so, how?

Comment: I use nVidia but the concept should be the same. Make sure you alter the aspect ratio drop down, it may be hiding the resolution under it. (Can not test this as I am not at home currently)

Comment: I am working on it right now, but I cannot log into the game again due to the *North American emergency maintenance*.  I will post pictures shortly - but its looking possible!

Comment: @MichelAyres I have posted more details as I did get it to work.  See pictures below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have confirmed this is possible by part of Shinrai's answer, but I feel more detail is needed:

1. Put the video card(s) into eyefinity and create your desktop
2. Load Diablo 3, click on **Options**
3. By default, you will be looking at the video options.  Change Display view to **Fullscreen Windowed** (click to view fullscreen)
   [image]
4. Notice: Resolution will be grayed out!  Do not worry. (click to view fullscreen)
   [image]
5. Apply, and Accept. This will automatically fill the screen to the size you specified as your eyefinity desktop resolution.
6. You will now notice that the home screen is rather messed up.  I'm sure Blizzard will patch this at a later time. (see picture directly below for IRL *Sorry for poor quality*)
   [image]
   Here is the screenshot(click to view fullscreen):
   [image]
7. Login, and select your player.  The displayed gameplay will work perfectly (see picture directly below for IRL *Sorry for poor quality*)
   [image]

Here is an in-game screenshot (click to view fullscreen):
[image]

```
    (ATI CCC version 12.3)
```

Comment: And yes... my coffee **DID** turn into a diet coke.

Comment: Great answer that I'm just now seeing; all my experience with Eyefinity is work-related, and I couldn't throw D3 on a system at the office just to test this myself.  Glad to see it works well!

Comment: Any reason for the down vote?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this firsthand, but apparently in the beta you were able to select the 'fullscreen windowed' mode where it renders in a window without the borders, pseudo-fullscreen) to support nonstandard resolutions like this.

[Here are a few reports of people doing the same in the retail release](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4078817889).