# Windowed Full Screen - Multi Monitor Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

I have a Multi-Monitor setup with 3 screens using my 2 GTX 580's

I would love to use the Windowed Full Screen video option however when I check this with 1920x1080 it stretches the screen across all 3 monitors.

Normally I would be thrilled, but I happen to think it detracts from the experience and I would rather use the other two screens for something more productive.

I have tried messing around in the NVidia Control Panel to no effect...

Comment: So you just want to use the middle screen for your gaming? and not the outer two ( far left and far right monitor)?  I am kind of confused what you are looking for

Comment: Exactly! I cant seem to get it with just the middle monitor on game . If in regular full screen, the other 2 just turn black.

Comment: Try pressing alt+tab to get back to your desktop and then click on D3 again.  This happens with a few of my games too with tri monitors.

Comment: Which mode am I trying this in? Fullscreen? Windowed Fullscreen? I would just use windowed mode, but it looks horrible and I accidently resize the window all the time, plus the bottom half is cut off and the Windows task bar is on top...

Comment: Question: Do you have your video card set up right now to display the desktop as one giant desktop?  Use Fullscreen with 1920x1080 (if possible).  Your left and right monitor should be black now.  Hit Alt + tab to get to your desktop.  Then click on your D3 again.  The far left and far right monitor should be showing your desktop now [ This can be 'finicky' as you might have to do it a few times ]

Comment: I Provided a walkthrough on how to do the opposite of what you are trying to achieve [reverse engineering + alt+tab will do it ] here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66460/how-can-i-set-diablo-3-to-work-across-3-monitors-in-eyefinity-6016-x-1080-res/66660#66660

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go once I get home and let you know. I appreciate the feedback. Answer-Yes, I am working with 5760x1080 + bezel correct.

Answer (score 2):

As I specified above in the comments, if you would like your tri-monitor setup to only be full screen in the center and have your far left & far right monitor viewing the desktop (for multitasking purposes), do the following:

- Go into settings, Video: Make sure you are in **Fullscreen Mode**
- Recommended 1920 x 1080 resolution, but it is up to your hardware and personal preferences for display resolution
- *Be sure to save those settings*

Now, if this hasn't happened already, you should notice that your computer has grabbed **focus** of Diable III.  The far left and far right monitors are black - with the center monitor showing your game.

- Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get focus of your desktop ( this should minimize your game)
- Click the current running [ & hidden ] game of Diablo III to regain focus of that application
- This should now have your game in the center screen, with your desktop on your far right and far left monitor

*If this does not work on your first try, try again until you gain focus of your game with your desktop on the other two monitors.  Your system, by default, will want full focus of the game: hence why it blacks out the other two monitors.  From my experience this occurs in many other games today with a multiple monitor setup and Alt + Tab is the **easiest** way of gaining viewable access to your desktop.*

**Note:** It does **not** matter if you have your video card setup in eyefinity (or the NVidia equivalent of one giant desktop across 3+ monitors)

Comment: I can not get this to work. I have tried about 20 times now.. Not sure what I am missing so far.

Comment: I AM clicking on the Diablo 3 icon on my task bar to go back into Diablo 3, correct?

Comment: Thats correct.... I can provide a video if you would like.  It shouldnt take that long. But like I said, this can be *Finicky*

Comment: I still cant get it :-( If you would? Def + Rep

Comment: I can provide a little video on it.  Although it may take me some time to do it, and it will be a third person shot of it.

Comment: Is there a different way to force the game to keep 1920x1080 instead of 5760x1080 which in no way was specified? Some config file? Something in the Nvidia Control Panel?

Comment: Try taking your display options in Nvidia out of eyefinity (one GIANT desktop).  Change it to **extend Display** (might have to do this twice per each monitor to the left and right of your center display)

Comment: Would other games (Battlefield 3) still be able to use eyefinity? I do like it, just not for Diablo 3.

Comment: Yes.  Battlefield 3 does support it, but I have noticed with my setup ~1-2 seconds of video lag when playing it - so I normally play it with only 1 screen to avoid that lag (my main screen) 1920x1080 with my stats on my left screen and TeamSpeak on my right :D

Comment: It works but I basically turn AA off.... Kind of depressing.   I'm waiting for 2 680's...